# Dynamically allocating and printing values using malloc() [Pointer notation]

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SUITS 4
#define RANKS 13
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define MAX 9
typedef struct
{
        char *rank;
        char *suit;
        char *colour;
}Card;

Card* make_deck();
void print(Card*);

int main()
{

        Card *deck = make_deck();

        printf(" ***************Original Deck ***************\n");
        print(deck); /*print original deck */


        return 0;
}
Card* make_deck()                                                                 {
       
        char *ranks[] = { "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "Ace" };
        char *suits[] = { "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };

        /*allocate space for 52 cards on the heap */
        Card * deck=malloc(DECK_SIZE * sizeof(char));

        /*put cards into the space */
        for(int i=0;i<DECK_SIZE;i++){
                deck[i].rank = ranks[i%RANKS];
                


        /*Set the ranks,suits and colours of the cards  */
        strncpy(deck[i].suit, suits[i/RANKS], MAX);
        return deck;
}
}

/*print the deck to the screen*/
void print(Card *deck) {
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<DECK_SIZE;i++){
            printf("%5s of %-12s",deck[i].rank,deck[i].suit);

    }
}
```

I was going through my C program and stored the values of cards (suits, ranks) in corresponding arrays but get segmentation fault every time I run my program. I'm not sure where am I doing the mistake.
Any suggestion is welcome
Thanks.

Comment: `Card * deck=malloc(DECK_SIZE * sizeof(char));` Why would you use `char` for the size? It should be `sizeof(*deck)` or `sizeof(Card)`

Answer (score 1):

You mean to allocate space for 52 `Card`s, but you allocated space for 52 `char`s. The line where you allocate memory should be
`Card * deck = (Card *) malloc(DECK_SIZE * sizof(Card));`